# How to step line by line while debugging in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

For example I have this code:

```
category.items.each do |item|
  price = get_item_price(item)
  ...
end
```

And breakpoint on fist line:

```
category.items.each do |item|
```

I want just stepping line by line. 
When I press `F7` (Step into) it takes me to `define_readers [association.rb:110] (ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::Association)`

When I press `F8` (Step over) it just step to `end`

So is there any way to step line by line?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use pry gem: https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger

Comment: But I want to set breakpoints without typing code as ‘debugger/binding.pry’ and to use code inspection and evaluation during debugging runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to break at each iteration of the loop, I suggest putting a breakpoint at the first line within the loop:

```
price = get_item_price(item)
```

Then to get to the next iteration, you hit the resume button (F9 I believe) so that it will break again at the same point on the next iteration. From there you should be able to step through each line within the current iteration

Comment: Agree, but if I start to debug few lines before loop I have to toggle at least one more breakpoint, and if I have one loop inside another one - toggle two breakpoints